# How to divide that in this situation

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have problem that divide to TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY as 60. My english is not very well by the way. Guys help me

```
COUNT(CASE
      WHEN SERVICE_TYPE IN (0, 100)
      AND TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY / 60
      THEN RECIPIENT END) AS MOC_VOICE_CHARGED_DURATION
```

Comment: You want to check TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY can be divided by 60 with no remainder?

Comment: please post some sample data and needed result (formatted text, non images) to clarify your need

Answer (score 1):

as per the sql provided,below are my understanding:
you want to have count of recipient only when service type in (0,100) and when TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY is divideable by 60 i.e., meaning its remainder would be zero...
if that is the case then we can use the requirements as where condition , as shown below... (it can be altered as per required in case statement also if needed)

```
select count(receipient)
from  ...
...
where
....
service_type in (0,100)
and mod(TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY,60) = 0
....;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not checked `(TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY / 60)` this with any value

```
    COUNT (CASE
      WHEN SERVICE_TYPE IN (0, 100)
      AND (TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY / 60)=some_value
      THEN RECIPIENT END
      ) AS MOC_VOICE_CHARGED_DURATION
```

i would rewrite your query like below

```
     sum (CASE
      WHEN SERVICE_TYPE IN (0, 100)
      AND (TOT_MGCV_USE_QTY / 60)=some_value
      THEN 1 else 0 END
      ) AS MOC_VOICE_CHARGED_DURATION
```